# Permissions changing on few files under /etc/

Tags: permissions, rhel, etc

It appears that new permissions on `/etc/issue` and `/etc/motd` are reverting back to the original even if we change them. This is on systems running RHEL 5 and RHEL 6.  Is there any rc script which controls the permissions on `/etc` files?

Comment: What distro are you using?

Answer (score 1):

#### Debian

If you're using a Debian based distro then this is likely what's causing your issue.

- [motd - Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/motd)

*excerpt*

> #### /etc/motd in Debian
>
> Debian has a peculiar way of handling `/etc/motd`. The motd is updated at every reboot, in a boot script (`/etc/init.d/bootmisc.sh` in lenny and below, `/etc/init.d/bootlogs` in squeeze and above), which basically runs the following:
>
> ```
>    uname -snrvm > /var/run/motd
>    [ -f /etc/motd.tail ] && cat /etc/motd.tail >> /var/run/motd
> ```
>
> Since `/etc/motd` is a symlink to `/var/run/motd` in Debian, this works.
>
> #### How to update your /etc/motd
>
> Since `/etc/motd` basically gets overwritten at every reboot, you need to instead update `/etc/motd.tail` and either reboot (!!) or also edit `/etc/motd.tail` or run the above commands. There is a bug report (<del>[437176](http://bugs.debian.org/437176)</del>) to provide an easier command to allow you to update only `/etc/motd.tail`.

#### Red Hat based distros (Fedora/CentOS/RHEL)

For these types of distros I'm not aware of any automated system that would revert these files back to known versions as part of a reboot. These files are often times statically included on these systems in RPM packages such as these:

*CentOS 5.x*

```
$ rpm -qf /etc/issue /etc/motd
centos-release-5-9.el5.centos.1
setup-2.5.58-9.el5
```

*CentOS 6.x*

```
$ rpm -qf /etc/issue /etc/motd 
centos-release-6-5.el6.centos.11.2.x86_64
setup-2.8.14-20.el6_4.1.noarch
```

*Fedora 19*

```
$ rpm -qf /etc/issue /etc/motd 
fedora-release-19-8.noarch
setup-2.8.71-1.fc19.noarch
```

Further more a simple search for `/etc/issue` or `/etc/motd` within `/etc` turns up no such mechanism.

```
$ sudo grep -r /etc/issue /etc/*
```

Comment: What package does the file `/etc/motd` and `/etc/issue` show they're a part of? `rpm -qf /etc/motd /etc/issue`.